# Award bounty indicator appears on deleted answers

Tags: bug, bounties, deleted-answers

Minor UI glitch: The button to award a bounty is active on a deleted answer. Clicking on it results in the "THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!" alert.

> [image]

After confirming, I get the following error though:

> [image]

So not a fatal bug, but still better not show the +50 next to deleted posts.

Comment: 99% sure it won't go through, but for the sake of the 1% that it will, guess better not try. :)

Comment: I spent 50 repz to be sure, added screenshot now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hopefully on a worthy post. :)

Comment: Yeah, now Tim will get it. (well, in 48 hours :-))

Comment: Clearly the message should be changed to "THIS CANNOT BE DONE!" :)

Comment: I too got puzzled by this, as I awarded a bounty [on the most upvoted open/unanswered question ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247880/getting-associated-type-synonyms-with-template-haskell?noredirect=1#comment53122505_17247880), and it has a bunch of deleted questions, all with the blue button seemingly allowing me to award the bounty to a deleted answer. My original guess was: if a deleted a. is so good it deserves a bounty, it will get undeleted, right?